# hide price and add_cart for anonymous user in drupal

Tags: php, drupal-7

How do I hide price and add_to_cart option for anonymous users in Drupal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, You can go page dmin/people/permissions and uncheck this option for anonymous.

To hide fields you can create node--YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE.tpl.php

In this template you can check user-role:

```
global $user;

// Check if the user has the 'authenticated user' role.
if (in_array('authenticated user', $user->roles)) {
  //show your field 
}
```

Also you always can hide from css -)

.not-logged-in .YOUR_CLASS_FIELD {display: none;}